# IntelliJ gives incorrect "Condition is always false" warning

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am learning Kotlin by doing exercises on exercism.com. I am currently working on [triangles](https://exercism.org/tracks/kotlin/exercises/triangle). Part of my solution is like this:

```
class Triangle<out T : Number>(a: T, b: T, c: T) {
    init {
        require (a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0)
    }
}
```

On the line with `require()`, IntelliJ gives the warning:

```
Condition 'a != 0 && b != 0' is always false 
Condition 'a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0' is always false
```

I have the following tests:

```
class TriangleTest {
    @Test
    fun `equilateral - all sides are equal`() {
        assertTrue(Triangle(2, 2, 2).isEquilateral)
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException::class)
    fun `equilateral - all zero sides is not a triangle`() {
        assertFalse(Triangle(0, 0, 0).isEquilateral)
    }
}
```

Both of these pass. If IntelliJ's warning were correct, then one of these would fail. Why does IntelliJ give this incorrect warning?

Comment: Is this your full code for `Triangle` class? For me, IntelliJ doesn't produce this warning.

Comment: Note however that this code is probably not what you want. In Kotlin you can't compare numbers of different types without converting them implicitly. In above case `T` is unknown, so the compiler can't create `0` value of the corresponding type. It uses just `Any.equals(Any)` here which always returns `false` for integers of different types. In other words, it will work properly only for `Int`, but e.g. `Triangle(1L, 0L, 3L)` won't throw, because `0L != 0` is `true`. I may be wrong, but I think you can't create this class generic for all `Number` subtypes.

Comment: @broot No, this isn't the full code of `Triangle`, but it is enough to illustrate the thing I'm asking about. Interesting that you are not getting this warning. I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2022.2 Beta. What version are you on?

Comment: @broot Will you post this as an answer? That most likely describes the cause of the warning.

Comment: I asked about additional code, because the compiler/IDE analyzes the code to get insights about the data flow, possible values, etc. This warning may be a result of conclusions from some other code that you didn't provide. For example, if before that code you throw an exception if `a != 0` then IDE can deduce above expressions are always false. Above problem with generic number may be a reason for this warning, although I'm not sure about it. Note that in the case of e.g. `Long`,  these expressions are always true, not always false as the warning says.

Comment: @broot Thank you for your help so far. To clarify, while the code I show here is in a larger project that has more code, what I have here is sufficient to recreate the issue. I double checked before posting it.